# On sufficients conditions for $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\to \infty$

Tags: limits, analysis, asymptotics

Consider two nonnegative functions $f,g$ on $(0,\infty)$ and assume that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is $x(\varepsilon)>0$ such that
$$
f(x)\leq x^\varepsilon g(x), \quad \forall x>x(\varepsilon).
$$

**Question** Is this sufficient to claim that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\to \infty$?

Comment: No: take $f(x)=g(x)\log(1+ x)$, for any $g$ that isn't eventually $0$.

Comment: By considering $f/g$, you're asking what $\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} O(x^\varepsilon)=\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} o(x^\varepsilon)$ is.

Comment: If you can get rid of the dependence of $x(\varepsilon)$ on $\varepsilon$ then yes